# Passing a 2-D array to a function returns an unexpected output

Tags: c, arrays, vector

This program is meant to calculate the length of multiple vectors and sort them by size afterward, I wrote a function VL with a 1-dimensional array as input as well as the length of the aforementioned array and tested it in another program and it seems to work fine.

VL function

```
double VL(double w[], int num)                         /*Calculate vector length*/
{

int k;
double presqrt;
double length = 0;

for (k = 0; k < num; k++)
{
    presqrt += w[k] * w[k];
}
length = sqrt(presqrt);

return length;
}
```

Main function (The majority of this function had already been given.) Under the line, I wrote a small for loop to test if the function returned the correct magnitudes with this input.

```
int main(void)
{
int dim, num ;
int i, j;
double **w;

scanf("%d %d",&dim,&num);                            /* read N and M */
w = calloc(num, sizeof (double *));                   /* allocate array of M        pointers */
for(i=0; i<num; i++)                                /* allocate space for N dimensional vector */
{
    w[i]= calloc(dim,sizeof(double));              /* read the vector */
    for (j=0; j<dim ; j++)
    {
        scanf("%le",&w[i][j]) ;
    }
}
```

---

```
for(i=0; i<num; i++)                        /*printing vector lengths(test)*/
{
    printf("%.2f\n", VL(w[i], num));
}
```

---

```
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Please fix this `double presqrt;` to this `double presqrt = 0.0;`. Let me know if it helped

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `VL` function you add the result of the multiplication to `presqrt`

```
presqrt += w[k] * w[k];
```

However the initial value of `presqrt` was not defined.

Please initialize it to 0.0 at the very beginning inside `VL` function:

```
double presqrt = 0.0;
```